# Login - Filling form and submitting

Tags: java, api, http-status-codes, http-method

I an new to java and I need help. I am trying to login to a website using java, and everything seems to be fine until now. I get the response back and everything, but It doesn't attempt to log in, which is kind of weird..

The response I get when I run the code is:

```
Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://mrpropop.com/login
Post parameters : login=admin&password=admin
Response Code : 200
+website html/css code
```

Here is my code:

```
package practice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class login {

    private HttpURLConnection conn;

    public login() {
        // make sure cookies is turn on
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    }

    public String sendPost(String url, String params) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // Acts like a browser
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "mrpropop.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.length()));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(params);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + params);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        return getResponse();
    }

    private String getResponse() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = br.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        login login = new login();

        // 1. login first
        String loginUrl = "http://mrpropop.com/login";
        String loginParams = "login=admin&password=admin";
        login.sendPost(loginUrl, loginParams);

        // Post request
        String apiUrl = loginUrl;
        String apiParams = loginParams;
        System.out.println(login.sendPost(apiUrl, apiParams));

    }
}
```

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Class names should be uppercase in Java.

Comment: Why should it be uppercase, does it matter or change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do something when you get a code 200.

For example setting a cookie.

Comment: I really tried everything and it still doesn''t work.

Answer (score 0):

The response code of 200 suggests you have successfully logged in.  You can display the contents by querying the HTTP body from the response object.

Comment: It doesn't log in. I checked the database where it records every attempt at success and failure login.